# 2D array - look up table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, state

I am writing code for Robot moving on a floor in the room ( considered center of the floor is origin (0,0)). Robot can move in any direction(south, east, west, north), touching different vertices in the floor. I would like to know how many unique vertices it touched. 
For this, I am using a dynamic 2D array which records each stores vertex touches. So, the logic like this...if robot touches a vertex, that vertex will be checked in the array. If it is there, I do not increment my counter. At the end, I will get all unique vertices robot touched.

Is there any other better approach to find unique vertices robot touches.

Thanks.

I am writing code in C#. Size of the floor x-axis(-1,00,000 to 1,00,000), y-axis(-1,00,000 to 1,00,000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of the floor. If it is small, then your approach is probably the best. Alternatively, if the floor size is so large that it is impractical to keep a complete map of it in memory, then rather use an associative array (or whatever the equivalent is in C#) with vertex coords as keys, and a simple boolean as the value, which will only record the vertices actually visited.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Size of the floor x-axis(-1,00,000 to 1,00,000), y-axis(-1,00,000 to 1,00,000).

Comment: assuming that mean one hundred thousand (or even more so if 1 million), you should probably go with the sparse list (associative array) option.

Comment: Srilak, thanks for your reply. If you use associative array, we need to many iterations with the elements in the array to check if visits or not. Let us assume Robot travelled 1,00,000 steps in east direction, creates 1,00,000 entries in the associate array.

Comment: you could always use a linked list/hash table, or any other sparse storage data structure. No matter what, you're going to have to store 1,00,000 "pieces" of data. If your associative array already has problems at that size, a 200000x200000 grid is only going to be worse. Is memory an issue though? The way I see it, even on a 64 bit machine that should only take up 1.5Mb or so. If memory is a constraint (developing for a cellphone/embedded system for eg) then you'll have to get fancy and start bit-squishing.

Comment: Actually, forget bit squishing. Consider this problem. The robot starts at the centre, and moves in a spiral outwards. Eventually it will have visited every vertex exactly once, i.e. your worst case scenario. You're best bet is to store the moves the robot makes, and run length encode them. Then write a function that checks whether a particular vertex is in the those traversed by the robot. You can encapsulate the whole thing in a class and make it function like a set too. Sure the lookup function is painful, but the storage benefits are huge.